# How to simplify multiple constructors?

Tags: c#, constructor, visual-studio-2005, multiple-constructors

I would like to have two constructors for a class, as follows:

```
public MyClass()
{
    // do stuff here
}

public MyClass(int num)
{
    MyClass();
    // do other stuff here
}
```

Is the above the correct way to achieve my purpose?  Is there some kind of shorthand which is better?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
public MyClass()
{
    // do stuff
}

public MyClass(int num)
    : this ()
{
    // do other stuff with num
}
```

The `: this()` bit is called a **Constructor Initialiser**.  Every constructor in C# has a an initialiser which runs before the body of the constructor itself.  By default the initialiser is the parameterless constructor of the base class (or `Object` if the class is not explicitly derived from another class).  This ensures that the members of a base class get initilised correctly before the rest of the derived class is constructed.

The default constructor initialiser for each constructor can be overridden in two ways.

1. The `: this(...)` construct specifies another constructor in the same class to be the initiliser for the constructor that it is applied to.
2. The `: base(...)` construct specifies a constructor in the base class (usually not the parameterless constructor, as this is the default anyway).

For more details than you probably want see the C# 4.0 language specification section 10.11.

Answer (score 7):

The correct syntax looks like this:

```
public MyClass() 
{ 
    // do stuff here 
} 

public MyClass(int num) : this()
{ 
    // do other stuff here 
}
```

Note the `this()` at the second constructor. This calls the constructor in the same class with no parameters.

You could also have it the other way around:

```
public MyClass() : this(someReasonableDefaultValueForNum)
{ 
} 

public MyClass(int num)
{ 
    // do all stuff here 
}
```

There is only one more "function" you can use instead of `this` at this place which is `base`:

```
public MyClass(int num) : base(someParameterOnTheBaseClassConstructor)
{
}
```

This is useful if you don't want to call the default parameterless constructor in the base class but one of the constructors that takes parameters.

Comment: This is known as constructor-chaining.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
public MyClass()
{
    // do stuff here
}

public MyClass(int num) : this()
{

    // do other stuff here
}
```

Comment: Can any other function be substituted for `this()` in this context?

Comment: @CJ7 It's not a function. It's a special syntax construct. Only `this(..)` and `base(..)` are permissible. See [Using Constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use one constructor with a default value for the parameter:

```
public MyClass(int num = 0)
{
    MyClass();
    // do other stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
public MyClass()
   : this(1) { }

public MyClass(int num)
{
   //do stuff here
}
```